# Optimization question in Calculus review package.

Tags: calculus, optimization

Terry makes and sells necklaces. He has observed over time that when the price is 12 dollars each, he sells an average of 22 per day. If he increases the price, then his average sales fall by 2 per day for each dollar increase. The materials for each necklace cost $5. Express his profit P as a function of x, the number of necklaces sold.

My work:

average number of necklaces sold $= 22 - 2t$

Revenue generated, $R = (22 - 2t)(12 + t) = -2t^2 - 2t - 264$

cost of neck laces $= 5(22 - 2t) = 110-10t$

Profit $=$ Revenue $- \text{ Cost } \text{( I think..?)} = 154 + 8t - 2t^2$

we find that if we isolate $22-2t = x \text{ we get } t = 22-x / 2$

Plug that into the Profit formula and we end up with $(-8x - x^2) / 2$

That is not the correct answer because I am putting this into an online calculus website that checks if it's correct.

Comment: I think you meant to write $R = (22 - 2t)(12 + t) = -2t^2 - 2t - 264.$

Comment: Oops yeah, my bad, typo >.<

Answer (score 0):

Taking $t = (22-x)/2,$
I plugged this into the profit function in Wolfram Alpha and got
$18 x- \frac{x^2}{2}.$

There appears to be an arithmetic error somewhere in your expansion of
the profit formula after substituting for $t.$
I don't think the problem was that you used $22-(\frac x2)$ instead
of $(22-x)/2,$ because that leads to a very different answer than either of ours.
In any case, I don't see any other errors in your calculations.